# um bug na função range()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debug

Estive escrevendo uma função para uma classe que pega um dicionario e converte em uma string para representar uma matriz.

```
def __str__(self):

    grid_str = ['' for _ in range(self.heigth)]

    for y in range(self.heigth):

        for x in range(self.heigth):

            grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[y, x])

    string = ""
    for line in grid_str:
        string = string + line + "\n"
    return string
```

Mas ela dá o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jean/Dropbox/game of life 2/core.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(g.__str__())
  File "C:/Users/Jean/Dropbox/game of life 2/core.py", line 41, in __str__
    grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[y, x])
KeyError: (10, 0)
```

Então resolvi resolvi colocar uma chamada de print pra debugar.

```
def __str__(self):

    grid_str = ['' for _ in range(self.heigth)]

    for y in range(self.heigth):

        for x in range(self.heigth):

            print(x, ",", y)      #<<< chamada de print
            grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[y, x])

    string = ""
    for line in grid_str:
        string = string + line + "\n"
    return string
```

E o resultado foi o seguinte:

`0 , 0
1 , 0
2 , 0
3 , 0
4 , 0
5 , 0
6 , 0
7 , 0
..., ...
..., ...
43 , 9
44 , 9
45 , 9
46 , 9
47 , 9
48 , 9
49 , 9
0 , 10  # <<< ??`

Considerando que era uma matriz de 10x50, como assim `0 , 10`?
Que eu saiba a função range começa a contar a partir do zero e para e não retorna para zero, muito menos completaria com `y = 10` neste caso.
Bom, se alguém souber o que está havendo, fico agradecido :) .

```
class grid:
    grid = {}
    width = 0
    heigth = 0

    def __init__(self, width, heigth):
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = heigth
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(heigth):
                self.grid[x, y] = 0

    def set_region(self, replaceGrid, shift_X, shift_Y):
        for key, item in list(replaceGrid.items()):

            newkey = (key[0] + shift_X, key[1], shift_Y)
            self.grid[newkey] = item

    def rand_region(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, rate):
        from random import random
        for x in range(x1, x2):
            for y in range(y1, y2):
                if random() > rate:
                    v = 0
                else:
                    v = 1

                self.grid[x, y] = v

    st = str

    def __str__(self):

        grid_str = ['' for _ in range(self.heigth)]

        for y in range(self.heigth):

            for x in range(self.width):

                print(x, ",", y)
                grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[y, x])

        string = ""
        for line in grid_str:
            string = string + line + "\n"
        return string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = grid(10, 50)
    print(g.__str__())
```

Comment: no ciclo for interno, `for x in range(self.heigth):` nesta linha não será: `for x in range(self.width):`?

Comment: Sim mas os eixos X e y saem invertidos quando se chama o print.

Comment: Opa, agora vi, caramba que burrada minha.

Comment: Realmente, o colega @Miguel tem razão. O seu código parece ok (testei no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SN7p14) e não vi problema além do fato de potencialmente o seu laço em x estar erroneamente usando a altura ao invés da largura como limite).

Comment: que estranho, eu mudei o laço aqui e ainda está retornando para zero.

Comment: Então prepare um [mcve] que reproduza o problema, para que nós possamos testar. Como eu disse no meu comentário anterior, eu testei rapidamente o seu laço no Ideone e não reproduzi o problema que vc diz ocorrer.

Comment: https://repl.it/FUKo/0, fiz um pequeno teste e não voltou para 0. Tem como postar o código da classe inteira e a chamada que é feita? Ou joga aí no repl que fica até mais fácil de testar.

Comment: claro, achei que a pergunta ia ficar grande de mais, desculpem editei ela com o código completo.

Comment: @LuizVieira afinal o erro não era bem esse, foi mais um lapso de memória a curto prazo do colega Jeacom :P , respondi em baixo caso tenha curiosidade

Comment: @Miguel Ok, agora que o AP edito a pergunta incluindo não somente o código relevante como também a mensagem de erro, ficou mais clara. Vou retirar meu voto pra fechar.

Comment: Dica: a função "range" do Python é naverdade uma classe e deve ser usada todos os dias por milhões de desenvolvedores. É uma função relativamente simples, que devolve um objeto não muito complicado - e pessoas interessadas em entender Python mais a fundo em geral olham seu código fonte. Não, ela não tem um bug - se você acha que tem um bug em "range" ou em outra função muito usada no Python, o erro está no seu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ora bem Jeacom, tinhas um erro subtil, é assim:

neste block onde populas `self.grid` em `init`:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(heigth):
        self.grid[x, y] = 0
```

Estás a popular assim:

> self.grid[x, y] = 0

em que o `x` equivale a uma unidade de width e `y` equivale a uma unidade de height, ora bem, depois quando estás a tentar aceder às chaves neste bloco estás a inverter, estás tentar aceder com a ordem inversa da que populaste:

```
for y in range(self.heigth):
    for x in range(self.width):
        print(x, ",", y)
        grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[y, x])
```

Aqui x segundo elemento (que quando populamos era o primeiro) é uma unidade de width e o mesmo vale para a height:

Ou seja, correcção final:

```
...
for y in range(self.heigth):
    for x in range(self.width):
        print(x, ",", y)
        grid_str[y] = grid_str[y] + self.st(self.grid[x, y])
...
```

No fundo foi só inverter a ordem quando tentas aceder às chaves, fica:

```
self.grid[x, y]
```